# Can't take screenshot of hovered element in Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I'm trying to take a screenshot of an element with the hover effect, but the screenshots always come out without the hover effect.

```
    tableListMaps.lineWithText('Hello world', 'myLine');
    cy.get('@myLine').realHover().within(() => {
      highlightElement(commonMaps.BUTTON_DOWNLOAD_INLINE);
    });
    cy.screenshot('downloadScreenshot');
```

If I later on come back and hover over this element, I can see what I was trying to highlight was highlighted successfully, but it wasn't captured by the screenshot.

Is there a way I could "fixate" the hover effect?

Comment: Got any info on `highlightElement` and also the library (if any) that does the hover - e.g `react-tooltip`? Makes your question more reproducible.

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR what highlightElement does is basically add a circle on the selected element with this css property: 'rgb(0, 255, 208) solid 3.75px'. The hover library is cypress-real-events (https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events). Looks like Cypress does some work before taking the screenshot that breaks the Hover, as the library developer pointed out: https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/issues/80

Comment: What is used in the **source app** to give you the hovered effect. Is it a CSS-driven hover as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) or are you using a library?

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR it was a CSS-driven hover. I managed to solve this by setting the CSS manually. Thanks for your support! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by dmtrKovalenko in [here](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/issues/80):

> Yeah this is likely impossible :)
> Cypress is doing some work in preparation between screenshot that will
> break hover

But I managed to do a workaround. The solution was to manually set the CSS expected in hovering state. Example:

```
    tableListMaps.lineWithText('Hello world', 'myLine');
    cy.get('@myLine').within(() => { 
      cy.get(commonMaps.BUTTON_DOWNLOAD_INLINE).then(($element) => {
        $element.css('visibility', 'visible');
      });
      highlightElement(commonMaps.BUTTON_DOWNLOAD_INLINE);
    });
    cy.screenshot('downloadScreenshot');
```

Since hovering over myLine would set the button visibility to "visible", what I did was just set it myself via CSS.

This way, I can take the screenshot as if the element was actually hovered. Then I set visibility to hidden again and background color to the original as well.

TL;DR: just simulate a hovering effect with CSS and take the screenshot.

```
cy.get(myElement).then(($element) => {
  $element.css('visibility', 'visible');
  $element.css('background-color', '#F2F2F2');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Known limitation. See [dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events docs](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#1-why-cyrealhover-hovering-state-does-not-show-in-the-visual-regression-services):

> 1. Why `cy.realHover` hovering state does not show in the visual regression services?
>
> Unfortunately, visual regression services like
> Happo and Percy do not solve this issue. Their architecture is based
> on saving dom snapshot, not the screenshot, and then rendering the
> snapshot on their machines. It means that the hover and focus state
> will be lost if it won't be serialized manually.
>
> It means that if you will use plain `cy.screenshot` it will take a
> screenshot with a hovering state because using the browser itself to
> make a screenshot. Testing hovering state is possible with, for
> example, Visual Regression Tracker and cypress-image-snapshot.

Comment: "It means that if you will use plain cy.screenshot it will take a screenshot with a hovering state because using the browser itself to make a screenshot." 
Shouldn't it work, then? I'm trying to use cy.screenshot to take a screenshot with the hovering state.

Comment: Pretty sure that’s a typo by the author.

Comment: You're quoting stuff that you think is a typo?

Answer (score 0):

tested it, working for me

```
cy.get('span')
      .contains('Header for All tenants')
      .realHover()
      .then((el) => {
        el.trigger('mouseover');
      });
    snapshot('hover-page', () => cy.get('body'));
```